# How to display every featured image of a post in a post in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a single page template called single-businesses.php which shows different brands and its information. However underneath, I want to show featured images of every post within this file. Is there any way to do this in wordPress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a `loop` to do that. Similar to how posts are displayed in your blog page. Just exclude `the_content()` and anything else you don't need. The following code will display only the featured images (which are referred to as `the_post_thumbnail()`):

```
<?php 
if ( have_posts() ) {
    while ( have_posts() ) {
        the_post(); 
        the_post_thumbnail();
    }  //end while
} //end if
?>
```

Comment: This only lists the featured image for that page. I want to display all featured images on a single.php page

Comment: No, it displays all featured images of all your posts. Where are placing the code?

Comment: in a file called single-businesses.php file

Comment: I'm using ACF file image by tje way

Answer (score 2):

Might be You are showing the all post under the page template using the loop (while loop), you can add the inside the loop

```
the_post_thumbnail();
```

to the code to display the featured image in the loop.

You can try this code on your template page to show featured images of every post within this file.

```
<?php
   $type = 'post';
   $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? absint( get_query_var('paged') ) : 1;
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => $type,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        // 'posts_per_page' => 3, // To display the number of post per page 
        'paged' => $paged,
   );
    $query = new WP_Query( $args );

    if (have_posts()) :
?>

    <?php
        // Start the loop.
        while ( $query->have_posts() ) : $query->the_post();
    ?>

            <?php
                if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) {
                    //the_post_thumbnail();
                        the_post_thumbnail( 'post-thumbnail', array( 'alt' => the_title_attribute( 'echo=0' ), 'class'  => "img-responsive" ) );

                        /* You can try other resolution also

                            the_post_thumbnail();                  // without parameter => Thumbnail
                            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail');       // Thumbnail
                            the_post_thumbnail('medium');          // Medium resolution
                            the_post_thumbnail('large');           // Large resolution
                            the_post_thumbnail( array(100,100) );  // Other resolutions 100px X 100px 
                        */

                }
            ?>
            <?php the_permalink(); // Link of the post ?>

         <?php the_title( sprintf( '<h3 class="title"><a href="%s">', esc_url( get_permalink() ) ), '</a></h3>' ); ?>

   <?php
        // End the loop.
        endwhile;
    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Please test it ones, I had not run the code on the template page.